# Using Filterrific in Rails to search through Active Record Associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I have a teacher model and a student model (teacher has_many students). Hoping to use Filterrific to search through teachers *by their students' names*.

The default functionality of filterrific is to search teachers based on SQL queries to the teachers table.

I'm wondering how I would be able to search teachers based on their associations' tables. Here is the SQL code in teacher.rb:

```
 scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
    return nil  if query.blank?
    # condition query, parse into individual keywords
    terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)
    # replace "*" with "%" for wildcard searches,
    # append '%', remove duplicate '%'s
    terms = terms.map { |e|
      (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
    }
    # configure number of OR conditions for provision
    # of interpolation arguments. Adjust this if you
    # change the number of OR conditions.
    num_or_conditions = 3
    where(
      terms.map {
        or_clauses = [
          "LOWER(teachers.first_name) LIKE ?",
          "LOWER(teachers.last_name) LIKE ?",
          "LOWER(teachers.email) LIKE ?"
        ].join(' OR ')
        "(#{ or_clauses })"
      }.join(' AND '),
      *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conditions }.flatten
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the sample code from a scenario where I use `includes` instead of `joins` because I need a right outer join. In that case I have to let Rails know that I'm referencing the students table.

I'm not sure if you actually need the `references` portion with `joins`. Give it a try without, and I'd be curious to know if it works.

```
scope :search_query_by_students, lambda { |query|
  return nil  if query.blank?
  # condition query, parse into individual keywords
  terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)
  # replace "*" with "%" for wildcard searches,
  # append '%', remove duplicate '%'s
  terms = terms.map { |e|
    (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
  }
  # configure number of OR conditions for provision
  # of interpolation arguments. Adjust this if you
  # change the number of OR conditions.
  num_or_conditions = 3
  where(
    terms.map {
      or_clauses = [
        "LOWER(students.first_name) LIKE ?",
        "LOWER(students.last_name) LIKE ?",
        "LOWER(students.email) LIKE ?"
      ].join(' OR ')
      "(#{ or_clauses })"
    }.join(' AND '),
    *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conditions }.flatten
  ).joins(:students).references(:students)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jo!! I did have to keep the references. Also, I had to remove students. from students.first_name, students.last_name, and students.email

Comment: I did not need to include the `references` call. http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/active_record_scope_patterns.html